# Firebase data notifications are not being sent

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

We are currently struggling with sending our firebase data notifications. As far as I can see, those are not being sent at all. Here is a screenshot from the firebase console:

[image]

Here is the piece of code that is responsible for sending in our spring boot server:

```java
    public boolean sendSilentPushMessage(String pushToken, Map<String, String> notificationPayload) {
        Message.Builder messageBuilder = Message.builder();

        // prepare message with body
        Message message = messageBuilder
            .putAllData(notificationPayload)
            .setToken(pushToken)
            .build();

        // send notification to Firebase
        try {
            final var messageId = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(firebaseApp).send(message);
            log.debug("Sent silent firebase push notification: " + messageId);
            return true;
        }
        catch (FirebaseMessagingException e) {
            log.warn("Could not send firebase silent push notification", e);
            return false;
        }
   }
```

I can see the log that the firebase message is being sent (including the message id):

[image]

How can I further debug this? There is no exception being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us an example what kind of payload you are sending. A data notification is a notification that doesn't have any of the UI notifications fields filled-in.

Example: 'normal' notification

```js
const singleMessage: admin.messaging.Message = {
  android: {},
  apns: {},
  data: {}, // Optional
  token: token
}
```

Data notification:

```js
const singleMessage: admin.messaging.Message = {
  data: {},
  token: token
}
```

If it has any of the APNS or Android fields it will always been seen as a 'normal' notification